# A question about continuous function on a closed interval and the supremum

Tags: calculus, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f$ be function that is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ and let $A=\{x \in [a,b] | f(x) = f(a)\}$.

(1) Prove that A is a non empty set.
(2) Prove that A is bounded above and conclude that $sup(A)$ exists.
(3) Prove that A has maximum, meaning that $sup(A) \in A$.
(4) Show by example that (3) is not true if $f$ is not continuous in the point $b$.

My answer:
(1) Because $a \in [a,b]$ and $f(a) = f(a)$ we get that $a \in A$ and therefore $A \neq \emptyset$.
(2) We will show that $\forall x \in A, x \leq b$:
Let $x \in A$ (there exists one since $A$ is non empty) then by definition of $A$ we get that $x \in [a,b]$ and therefore $a \leq x \leq b$ and in particular $x \leq b$ as was to be shown, therefore $A$ is bounded above and since $A \neq \emptyset$ we get by the supremum axiom/theorem that $sup(A)$ exists.
(3) We must show that $sup(A) \in A$:
first $\forall x \in A, x \leq sup(A)$ by definition of the supremum and since $a \in A$ we get that $a \leq sup(A)$, also since $A \subseteq [a,b]$ we get that $sup(A) \leq sup[a,b] = b$ and therefore $a \leq sup(A) \leq b$ which implies that $sup(A) \in [a,b]$.
From here I didn't managed to proceed, how do I show that $f(sup(A)) = f(a)$ ?
(4) The same thing. (Didn't managed to proceed).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $\sup(A)$. Then 
$$f(\sup(A))=f\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(a)=f(a)$$
so $\sup(A)\in A$. This also suggests how to find a counterexample when $f$ is discontinuous at $\sup(A)$.

Comment: How do you know that there exists such a sequence ? (I am learning Calculus 1 course and not yet learned about the limit of sequence)

Comment: @JohnSaita It's a standard theorem. What is your definition of $\sup(A)$?

Comment: @JohnSaita The sequence can be constructed by using the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem. By the definition of supreme, we can find a sequence $x_n$ such that $|x_n - \sup(A)| < \frac{1}{n}$, then there exists a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ that converges to $sup(A)$. And another way to finish this problem is seeing that since $f$ is continuous, then $A$ is closed (a function is continuous if and only if the pre-image of all closed sets are closed).

Comment: @Xiao The way you constructed the sequence, it already converges, you don't need Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a counter example for (4) but so far I failed

Comment: @JohnSaita Whenever you try to come up with a counterexample, you want to try to build the simplest counterexample possible so you can understand what's going on. So let's try making $f$ constant everywhere except $b$. What happens?

Comment: Thanks. Yes the counter example works well.